# Shell script suddently stopped working

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3, mysql

I found the following script online which makes backup of a database and uploads it to the S3 bucket:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Shell script to backup MySql database

# CONFIG - Only edit the below lines to setup the script
# ===============================

MyUSER="test"           # USERNAME
MyPASS="test"       # PASSWORD
MyHOST="localhost"      # Hostname

S3Bucket="test" # S3 Bucket

# DO NOT BACKUP these databases
IGNORE="information_schema mysql performance_schema phpmyadmin"

# DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING
# ===============================

# Linux bin paths, change this if it can not be autodetected via which command
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
CHOWN="$(which chown)"
CHMOD="$(which chmod)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

# Backup Dest directory, change this if you have someother location
DEST="/var/www/test/backup"

# Main directory where backup will be stored
MBD="$DEST/mysql-$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"

# Get hostname
HOST="$(hostname)"

# Get data in dd-mm-yyyy format
NOW="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"

# File to store current backup file
FILE=""

# Store list of databases
DBS=""

[ ! -d $MBD ] && mkdir -p $MBD || :

# Get all database list first

if [ "$MyPASS" == "" ];
then
  DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -Bse 'show databases')"
else
  DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
fi

for db in $DBS
do
    skipdb=-1
    if [ "$IGNORE" != "" ];
    then
        for i in $IGNORE
        do
            [ "$db" == "$i" ] && skipdb=1 || :
        done
    fi

    if [ "$skipdb" == "-1" ] ; then
        FILE="$MBD/$db.$HOST.$NOW.gz"
        # dump database to file and gzip
        if [ "$MyPASS" == "" ]; then
          $MYSQLDUMP -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
        else
          $MYSQLDUMP -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
        fi
    fi
done

# copy mysql backup directory to S3
s3cmd sync -rv --skip-existing $MBD s3://$S3Bucket/
```

So, I added a cron job to run it and ran it manually the first time, everything was OK and the backup  appeared in S3  bucket. But, starting from today, when I try to run it manually, I get dozens of errors:

```
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 48: [: test: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: information_schema: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: information_schema: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: information_schema: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: information_schema: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: information_schema: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 66: [: -1: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: mysql: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: mysql: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: mysql: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: mysql: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 62: [: mysql: unexpected operator
/var/www/test/backup/backup.sh: 66: [: -1: unexpected operator
```

Its like not accepting the list of databases nor the credentials for the mysql. And I havent touched those. What could be the reason for this? I tried uploading the script again, the same exact script, running it with regular user, `sudo sh ./backup.sh` but all without success. Im using a Ubuntu on Amazon EC2, so maybe something with permissions is causing this? (I set it as exectutabe `sudo chmod +x backup.sh`, tried with chown 777 but all without success.

Im not a shell scripting expert so this is confusing for me, I know my way around terminal but can't figure out why is this happening when the script wasn't altered at all.

Cron command is: `0 10 * * * /var/www/magicpin/backup/backup.sh` (with `sudo crontab -e`), maybe I should use `crontab -e` and change the cron to `0 10 * * * sudo sh /var/www/magicpin/backup/backup.sh`

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just to clarify why the script worked the first time. It appears the original script (which I later modified a bit, had a line which changed the permission on the directory). So, when I ran it first time, I could do it via ./backup.sh, from user Ubuntu. Next time, because the permissions were changed, that got me "permission denied", so thats when I started experimenting with `sh` and permissions and stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're `bash` script appears to be fine, I believe it is the way you are invoking it. `sh` and `bash` are different shells. Try running it like this:

```
sudo ./backup.sh
```

or

```
sudo bash ./backup.sh
```

instead of

```
sudo sh ./backup.sh
```

Comment: Indeed. In Ubuntu `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash` (same as in Debian), which doesn't provide the same features as `bash`. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/141932).